# How to show only the main activity in the recent apps list?

Tags: android

When I minimize my app I can see the last visited activity in the recent apps list, is there a way to change this behaviour to show only the screen shot of the main activity regardless to the last active activity?

Basically I want to see a screen shot of my main activity in recent apps and when I tap on it I need to be redirected to the main activity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - How to remove activity from recent apps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14523287/android-how-to-remove-activity-from-recent-apps)

Answer (score 0):

You can override `onResume()` method in other activities and place the code there that calls the Main activity.

Comment: I want the screen shot to show the main activity as well

Comment: Well then you might wanna try adding this to your manifest file for every activity but the Main one: noHistory="true". See more about noHistory [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836080/how-does-androidnohistory-true-work)